# Neo4j-admin import bad tolerance

Tags: neo4j

I have an neo4j-admin import script set up with `--bad-tolerance=100000` (note, also tried `--bad-tolerance 100000`) as a flag. My script fails during import during the `collect dense nodes` step with the following message: `unexpected error: Too many bad entries 1001, where last one was: InputRelationship:...`

I thought bad tolerance was supposed to address that flag so that it would fail at the (in this case) 100,001st bad entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bin/neo4j-admin import` is feature wise not yet on par with the good old `bin/neo4j-import` tool - which is marked deprecated in 3.1.1.

To use `--bad-tolerance` you need to go back to use `bin/neo4j-import`.

Comment: I'm curious about how to use `neo4j-admin import`. I can't find any documentation on it -- as a matter of fact this SO post was the top hit on my google search!